# Getting duplicate pdf with jsPDF

Tags: jspdf

I have just started using jsPDF for creating PDF. When I am saving it, it generates two PDF files at that time. The first PDF name is the same as I gave in the code but the second PDF name is any text (like: DXTRE5.pdf). I need only one PDF with the given file name. Please help me.

```
 $('#print').click(function () {
        var doc = new jsPDF();
        var chartHeight = 80;
        doc.setFontSize(15);
        doc.text(35, 25, "Prospect Report Graph");
         $('.myChart').each(function (index) {
            var imageData = $(this).highcharts().createCanvas();
            doc.addImage(imageData, 'JPEG', 45, (index * chartHeight) + 40, 120, chartHeight);
           });
         doc.save('reports_graph.pdf');     
    });
```

Comment: Not seeing more of your code, I would suggest to stop event propagation: https://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation/

Answer (score 0):

The code looks fine. This won't trigger any PDF export twice. It should be somewhere else where click binding of the **#print** should exist in your code. Check and find the code you could fix that issue.

That duplicate click binding may have line like `doc.save('DXTRE5.pdf');` find and remove that binding.

Comment: In my case it was because of repeating the doc.autoTable(res.columns, res.data, options);